# XML data gives error while trying to fetch

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, yii, simplexml

I have a XML like

```
print_r( $eachFeature->unit->attributes() );
```

wchich gives output

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [id] => m2 [size] => 76 ) )
```

and i used this code to extract

```
$eachUnitSize = (string) $eachFeature->unit->attributes()->size;
```

it gives a error

```
main(): Node no longer exists
```

i am doing this in Yii frame work.
if this is wrong then what should i do.. A help will b greatfull to me .. Thank You

Comment: Just to check, is the line that's erroring right next to the one successfully outputting a `print_r`, or is there any processing in between?

Answer (score 0):

Attributes in `SimpleXML` elements can be accessed like arrays:

```
$el = $eachFeature->unit->attributes();
$eachUnitSize = (string)$el['size'];
```

Comment: Actually, it can be even simpler than that - `(string)$eachFeature->unit['size']` would be the same thing. The 3 approaches are equivalent, though, so it doesn't explain the error encountered.

Comment: @IMSoP i need to check if it is exist or not first.. so what should i do ?

Comment: @SubhraSekharMukhopadhyay Check if *which node* exists? The general answer is `isset($some_simplexml_node)`, e.g. `isset($eachFeature->unit)`